# A basic SQL Server Backup strategy / tool

Tags: sql-server, backup, database-backups, backup-strategies, remote-backup

I have a SQL Server 2014 running on Windows Server 2012 R2. I want to back it up daily and store backups on some remote cloud storage for reliability. Basically, that is all of my requirements.

Is there a tool that can help with this? The easier and plainer the better.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any app providing native support for cloud backups.But you can use SQLServer 2014 to backup to cloud using SQLServer Agent

Below are steps

1.create credential

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL MyCredentialName
WITH IDENTITY = 'MyStorageAccountName',
SECRET = 'MyAccessKey';
```

2.Backup

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyNewDB TO  
URL = N'http://myserver.blob.core.windows.net/scarybu/MyNewDB.bak' 
WITH  CREDENTIAL = N'MyCredentialName', 
NAME = N'MyNewDB-Full Database Backup', STATS = 10;
```

You could also experiment by adding compression ,checksum to above syntax by looking at all options..You can see below link for more experiments and results done by Jovan Popovic :[Native database backup in Azure SQL Managed Instance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/10/16/native-database-backup-in-azure-sql-managed-instance/)..You can ignore copy_only syntax in the link examples,since it is only for managed instances

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you suggesting to do this using a Windows CMD script running by Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: You can use sqlserver agent

Comment: You can also take a backup locally and copy to blob daily thru task scheduler or any other scheduling mechansim

Comment: It seems this can be done from sql 2012 cu2  as well,see this link for best practices and troubleshooting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-and-restore-with-microsoft-azure-blob-storage-service